# Error in creating a linked server to SQL Azure database from a SQL Express instance “Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.”

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, linked-server

I am trying to setup a linked server to an Azure data warehouse using SQL Express 2019 on a vm. I have successfully created the linked server using a sql login but a AAD logins don't work.

I am using the following string

`Server=tcp:sqldw.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqldb;Persist Security Info=False;;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";`

**This is the error:**
Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: I updated the string to this  Server=tcp:sqldw.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sqldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated"; and it is giving me this error - Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Encrypt' (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are EF Core utilises v3.0 rather than [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso), starting with V3.0. Please have the latest [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](http://Azure%20AD%20Connect:%20Seamless%20Single%20Sign-On%20-%20How%20it%20works%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs) version at the moment (including preview versions) only supports those two NET Framework choices."

Note: NetCore programmes currently do not support `ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` or `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` authentication options.

Active Directory Integrated wasn't working in .NET Core 3.1 but it works now ever when installed the NuGet package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient// version v2.0.1. It now works with the following connection string:

"ipsdbconnstr": "Server=tcp:ipsdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDb;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"

With the additional properties, here is the example:

;User ID=userid@mydomain.com;Persist Security Info=true;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

The server name (or IP address) on a SQL Server SSL certificate must exactly match the server (or IP address) name given in the connection string when the `TrustServerCertificate` is set to false and Encrypt is set to true.

Otherwise, the effort to connect is infringed. In other words, the sole security check carried out is the combination of "`encrypt=true`; `trustservercertificate=false`", is to verify if the hostname certificate matches the server hostname to which you are connecting.

The `trustservercertificate=false` will not accept autosigned certificates, therefore it is still necessary to sign the certificate with a known/trustworthy CA.

Set the `TrustServerCertificate=true` to address the problem.

You should logged into Windows using your Azure Active Directory credentials from a federated domain, or a managed domain that is configured for seamless single sign-on for pass-through and password hash authentication.

Documents for your reference

[Azure Active Directory Seamless Single Sign-On.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso)

[Azure AD Connect: Seamless Single Sign-On - How it works | Microsoft Docs](http://Azure%20AD%20Connect:%20Seamless%20Single%20Sign-On%20-%20How%20it%20works%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs)